# Draw content without redrawing the background in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing a Tetris game using Jetpack Compose.
The game board is a grid of squares (2d array) and has a background color.
When any square is changed, I just want to redraw that square instead of redrawing the background color.

But I tried and it didn't work, here is the code I tried:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .drawBehind {
                println("drawOuter")
                drawRect(color = Color.Black, style = Stroke(width = 8.dp.toPx()))
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Green) }

        // trigger draw phrase
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            while (true) {
                delay(1000L)
                color = Color.Red
                delay(1000L)
                color = Color.Green
            }
        }

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .drawWithContent {
                    println("drawInner")
                    drawRect(color = color)
                }
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    Test()
}
```

Output: drawOuter and drawInner is always printed (called)
Can I draw content without redrawing the background in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but I have interesting findings. If you remove the .draw and add a log message inside the box it's not being printed. So it's the modifier that causes the redraw.